# SQL - If Param Null then omit criteria in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, null, where-clause, param

```
@TimeCurr Char(1)

SELECT RecordDate, a, b,c
FROM tbl_xyz
WHERE 1 = 1
AND
```

if @TimeCurr = 'Y' Then
RecordDate = GetDate()

if @TimeCurr = 'N' then
RecordDate <= GetDate()

if @TimeCurr = Null
then omit the critera altogether. How can we accomplish this?

Comment: `(ISNULL OR CASE ... END)`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT RecordDate, a, b,c
FROM tbl_xyz
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
      ((@TimeCurr = 'Y' AND RecordDate = CAST(GetDate() as date)) OR
       (@TimeCurr = 'N' AND RecordDate <= GetDate()) OR
       @TimeCurr IS NULL
      );
```

Based on the use of `GETDATE()`, I am guessing that you are using SQL Server.  If so, the function `GETDATE()` returns a date/time value.  You don't usually want to use `=` with it.  That is why I convert it to a date, assuming that `RecordDate` is actually a date with no time component.